# Java date question using oracle10g

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

I am trying to decode this little peice of java code (using an oracle10g database) from a left over program i am remaking in VB.net. Say i chose on the datepicker 01/02/11:

```
AND (due_date between (to_date('" + dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedPeriodSet().toString() 
+ "', 'MM/DD/YY') - 1) 
AND (to_date('" + dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedPeriodSet().toString() + "', 'MM/DD/YY') + 1) 
OR " + "begin_date between (to_date('" + dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedPeriodSet().toString() + "', 'MM/DD/YY') - 1) 
AND (to_date('" + dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedPeriodSet().toString() + "', 'MM/DD/YY') + 1))
```

Where the +1's are, is it adding a month (02/02/11) or day (01/03/11)? And for the -1's, is it subtracting a month (12/02/10) or a day (01/01/11)?

David

Comment: Whatever does pay the bills is good enough, huh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's subtracting/adding a day.

Try running:

```
select toDate('10/01/09', 'MM/DD/YY') - 1 from whatever_table
```

it should return:

```
09/30/09
```

Comment: If the database has '11/2/2009 3:00:20 PM' format how would i covert that to what i am trying to toDate? I've already tried **where to_date(BEGIN_DATE, 'MM/DD/YY')** but that gives an error.

Comment: Convert the comment to a question and you'll earn even more points :)

Comment: I just got a "Cleanup" badge for that :o)